# Discovering string "motifs" in python

Tags: python, clustering, data-cleaning, text

I have millions of strings from different sources that tend to exhibit some common patterns. Is there a way to extract these common motifs?

For example, in a list (of millions) that includes strings

```
['rs12346','rs1212122',...,'sxs-rs333',...,'kgp222']
```

..is there a way to extract the following patterns?

- 'rs' plus one or more digits
- 'sxs-rs' plus one or more digits
- 'kgp' plus one or more digits

Some other parameters:

- cleaning up beforehand isn't an option
- some manual tweaking would be possible (e.g. manually changing a pattern because of outside knowledge)
- exceptions (i.e. classifying less than 100% of the strings) can be tolerated
- an ideal solution would be using a built-in python library.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that letters are indicative of "motifs" and numbers are considered as digits and not exact numbers, this is what I would do:

First - transform numbers into a digit placeholder (`#`)

```
import re
s = re.sub("\d",s,"#")
```

Then I would transform a string into a bag-of-bigrams vector in the char level

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vecs = CountVectorizer(s, analyzer="char_wb", ngram_range=(1,3))
```

After these 2 steps, we got a sparse vector from any string:

```
'ab123' --> {" a":1,"ab":1,"b#","##":2,"# ":1}
```

Next we want to convert those vectors to a pairwise distance matrix and cluster by that distance.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
from scipy.cluster import  hierarchy
def link_cluster(X, threshold=0.1, metric="cosine", algo="average"):
    X = X.todense()
    Z = hierarchy.linkage(X, algo, metric=metric)
    C = hierarchy.fcluster(Z,threshold, criterion="distance")
    return C
```

Your end result would be

```
C = link_cluster(vecs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer also depends on your usecase. If you just want to detect these kind of strings I would focus on heuristic rules that suit my needs, rather than creating a system that learns to recognize the patterns of the strings.

However, if your aim is generating similar kind of strings based on the current patterns or finding new strings in a stream of text, you should look for regex generators. There is this [list of resources](https://github.com/aloisdg/awesome-regex) regarding regexes in general and you should focus on the generators for the task at hand.

For a similar task in the past, I had used an [online, free tool](http://regex.inginf.units.it/) that will generate a regex (if possible) that satisfies as many of your sample strings as possible. So you could give it a try, as a fast solution.

Either way, I would  first do some data exploration(e.g. are numbers and letters also intermixed or do numbers always come up after or letters/symbols etc.), in order to get a better understanding for the problem at hand. Also, this could lead to simple heuristic rules that could suffice as a crude solution or at least a simple baseline system against which I would "pitch" a machine learning model.